# OLEDB - Unable to Edit record in Access Database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, oledb

In my WinForms application, I am connecting to an Access (mdb) database. I have 2 tables in the database. MDB is not added to the project. It just avbl in the folder along the exe file of the app.

From the app, I am trying to add/edit records of the db. I could get connected to the DB, add records to DB but finding difficulty in editing the records. While the app is running, I find the db is updated with edited record, but on re-connecting to the DB the edited records doesn't exists i.e. records are not edited at all. The DB is just updated with edited records temporarily only & not permanently updated. This is my code :-

```
    public static OleDbConnection SetupConnection()
    {

        mainCon = new OleDbConnection();
        mainCon.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = ServiceStn.mdb;";
        try
        {
            mainCon.Open();

            // Fill Data DS
            FillAppointmentDS();
         ........ 


    // Fill AppointmentDS with Appointment Table data
    private static void FillAppointmentDs()
    {
        string todayDt = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");   

        aptDs = new DataSet();
        aptDa = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Appointment where appointDate = #" + todayDt + "#", mainCon);
        OleDbCommandBuilder aptCmdBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(aptDa);
        aptDa.Fill(aptDs, "Appointment");
        aptDa.FillSchema(aptDs, SchemaType.Source, "Appointment");

        return;
    }

    // Add new Appointment to the DB
    public static bool SaveAppointment(Models.Appointment apt)
    {
        DataRow dr = null;

        dr = aptDs.Tables[0].NewRow();

        dr["custID"] = apt.CustomerId;
        dr["appointDate"] = apt.AppointmentDate.Date;   // "17/9/2014";
        dr["appointTime"] = apt.AppointmentTime.TimeOfDay.ToString();
        dr["companyName"] = apt.AC_CompanyName;
        dr["model"] = apt.AC_Model;
        dr["problem"] = apt.AC_Problem;

        aptDs.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);

        int updatedRows = aptDa.Update(aptDs, "Appointment");
        Console.WriteLine("Updated Rows - " + updatedRows);
        dr = null;

        // Add Appointment to the AppointmentList
        appoints.Add(apt);

        if (updatedRows > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    // Update an existing Appointment in the DB
    public static bool UpdateAppointment(Models.Appointment apt)
    {
        DataRow dr = null;

        string filter = "aptID=" + apt.AppointmentId;

        dr = aptDs.Tables[0].Select(filter)[0];

        dr["appointDate"] = apt.AppointmentDate.Date;   
        dr["appointTime"] = apt.AppointmentTime.TimeOfDay.ToString();
        dr["companyName"] = apt.AC_CompanyName;
        dr["model"] = apt.AC_Model;
        dr["problem"] = apt.AC_Problem;

     //   OleDbCommandBuilder aptCmdBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(aptDa);

       // dr.AcceptChanges();
        aptDs.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
       // dr.SetModified();
        int updatedRows = aptDa.Update(aptDs.Tables[0]); //(aptDs, "Appointment");

        //int updatedRows = aptDa.Update(aptDs, "Appointment");
        Console.WriteLine("Updated Rows - " + updatedRows);
        dr = null;
        if (updatedRows > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

SaveAppointment() works smoothly, but UpdateAppointment() doesn't show the updated the record in DB on re-Connecting the app to DB.

Can anyone help me know why I am not able to edit records to DB permanently !! Where am I going wrong in the code ? I don't get any error/exception in the code. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in the UpdateAppointments

```
aptDs.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
```

should be removed, otherwise the status of the row changes to `Unchanged` and the subsequent call to `Update` doesn't find any row modified and thus it can't write your changes back to  the database-

The meaning of `AcceptChanges` is always a source of confusion.

When you modify a row its [RowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate(v=vs.110).aspx) property becomes [Modified](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowstate(v=vs.110).aspx).
When you call the `OleDbDataAdapter.Update` method, it searches all the rows in the table with a RowState like `Added`, `Deleted` or `Modified` and applies the OleDbCommands created by `OleDbCommandBuilder` appropriate for the state.

[AcceptChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges(v=vs.110).aspx) works on these states changing them back to Unchanged (and removing the Rows with the state Deleted from the DataTable container).
In this way, an Update following an AcceptChanges call, will not find any row to be eligible for writing back to the database.

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve. I was in the impression that AcceptChanges commits all changes made to the DB.

Comment: No, the DataTable and the DataSet are disconnected objects. They don't even know how to reach the database using their built in properties (no connection there). It is the OleDbDataAdapter that knows that bit of info essential to update the database.